# Google Chrome overlays additional border on top of other border in table

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table, border

The code in my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cxjsu8k4/2/) produces an orange border in a table spanning four columns, but the result is incorrect in Google Chrome, while it’s correct in Firefox:

```css
.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.tg td {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg th {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg .tg-c3ow {
  border-color: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top
}

.tg .tg-0pky {
  border-color: inherit;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top
}

.tg .tg-76qt {
  border-color: inherit;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top
}

.edittext {
  border-top: 2px solid orange !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-0pky" colspan="3"></th>
      <th class="tg-c3ow" colspan="3"><span style="font-weight:bold">Heading 1</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0pky" colspan="3"></td>
      <td class="tg-76qt" colspan="3">Main heading 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0pky" colspan="3"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky ">Text Sample 1</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky ">Text Sample&nbsp;&nbsp;2</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky ">Text Sample 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0pky ">Sample Text</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">Vertical Heading 1</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky edittext">Vertical Heading 2</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky edittext">ABC 1</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky edittext">ABC 2</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky edittext">ABC 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Output of Google Chrome:

[image: Chrome has an additional gray border on top of the orange border.]

Output of Firefox:

[image: However, Firefox shows the correct output: an unobscured, solid orange border.]

I tried setting the `outline` instead of the `border`, but the outline covers all sides, rather than just the top.

Comment: I am using chrome and I see border only for top, what is it missing?

Comment: @Manjuboyz orange color coming wrongly for this column Vertical Heading 2

Comment: but in firefox coming correctly

Comment: would you mind adding 2 snapshots of chrome and firefox?

Comment: Added image for both chrome and firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `colspan:"3"` under first `tr` is the culprit. I just validated both in **chrome** and **firefox** both looks same now.

> There are unnecessary code which can be removed, however I have not taken care of.

I have added below code and removed `colspan`

```
  <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
```

> Incase if you ask `NO` I don't want to add those code and you want to use `colspan` to fix the issue then answer is also `NO` since it is a browser specific bug, there are already few articles on this you can look into `colspan border issue` you will find few.

```css
.edittext {
  border-top: 2px solid orange !important;
}
```

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .tg {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
  }
  
  .tg td {
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    word-break: normal;
  }
  
  .tg th {
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    word-break: normal;
  }
  
  .tg .tg-c3ow {
    border-color: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top
  }
  
  .tg .tg-0pky {
    border-color: inherit;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top
  }
  
  .tg .tg-76qt {
    border-color: inherit;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top
  }
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-0pky" colspan="3"></th>
      <th class="tg-c3ow" colspan="3"><span style="font-weight:bold">Heading 1</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0pky" colspan="3"></td>
      <td class="tg-76qt" colspan="3">Main heading 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky ">Text Sample 1</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky ">Text Sample&nbsp;&nbsp;2</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky ">Text Sample 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0pky ">Sample Text</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky">Vertical Heading 1</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky edittext">Vertical Heading 2</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky edittext">ABC 1</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky edittext">ABC 2</td>
      <td class="tg-0pky edittext">ABC 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
      <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not the desired result as expected in the question.

Comment: ok.. would you mind explaining what that is? OP needed consistency across browser and I made that work or May be I didn't understand what you trying to saying.

Comment: @Manjuboyz brilliant 95% done only thing i am getting the default table border that i will take care

Comment: @user4642212 I hope now it is clear on the question? it solves OPs issue are you satisfied now?

Comment: @Mahadevan If you remove `colspan="3"` you won’t have a single table cell spanning three columns, but three _separate_ columns, regardless of how you style the borders.

Answer (score -2):

You have added *edittext* class to the *Vertical Heading 2* column mistakenly.

You just have to remove this class

Hope you got the solution

Thanks

Comment: Then use different class and apply css. If you use the same class it must be applied Heading 2

Comment: please explain by editing your post to include code snippet. and showing where was the error.

Comment: If you have to use this class to all fields then you have to add new class with border-top:2px solid orange !important; .